# Will there be a sound if we oscillate something at more than 10Hz?

Tags: acoustics, frequency

We all know that we hear sound due to vibration in air. So I was wondering if we make an oscillator which does not make any internal sound, but it oscillates at more than 20Hz will we able to hear any sound due to those vibrations in the air (assuming amplitude is loud enough that we can hear)?

Comment: Depends on the amplitude. If it's large enough, then there will be a "swooshing" sound due to turbulence even below the actual low frequency hearing threshold of roughly 20Hz. You can easily hear that noise around the ports of bass reflex speakers.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "does not make any internal sound"? Additionally, you say "more than 10 Hz", but you don't specify how much more. More can be as high as 1 kHz, which can be very much audible. Furthermore, you don't specify anything about the amplitude of the sound so it is free to interpretation. I suggest you try to add some more information and clarify the aforementioned points for people to be able to provide some educated answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will be a sound generated if we oscillate something in the air in the frequency range of $[0.1-20]\text{Hz}$. It's called [infrasound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrasound). The thing that people can't hear infrasound, doesn't invalidate it being a sound. Though, [some animals](https://www.pbs.org/wnet/nature/can-animals-predict-disaster-listening-to-infrasound/133/) can hear and produce infrasound as well. Such as Sumatran rhinoceros which produce sounds with frequencies as low as 3 Hz, or alligators which are known to use infrasound to communicate over distances.